# How Do I Convert a Month Name into a Month Integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

If I start with a string: "March", how can I get the integer for that month?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [Date::MONTHNAMES](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html):

```
Date::MONTHNAMES.index("June") 
=> 6
```

Also note there is an equivalent for abbreviated month-names - [Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html):

```
Date::ABBR_MONTHNAMES.index("Jun") 
=> 6
```